# How do I go about making a GUI- enabled desktop app in "pure" ISO C++

Tags: c++, desktop

I am trying to make my first desktop app, but I am at my wit's end trying to understand C++/CLI. After several hours of trial and error, it seems to me that it is unrelated with C++( I may be wrong ). I am getting hard time making functions, classes, etc. work, and am unable to understand what is going on. So, I have decided to abandon it for the moment.

Please tell me whether I can make a GUI-enabled desktop app in "pure" C++, using just my Dev C++ compiler. Yes, it might be a better idea to use visual studio, but I want to return to it later. Right now, please tell me whether I can do it in "pure" C++, and if yes, how(i.e., any books, tutorials or some specific learning path).

And yes, the app is just for my learning purpose. So, the issues of cross-platform compatibility, etc. can be safely ignored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: standard C++ does not come with gui.

Comment: If you're learning C++ and have a hard time doing so writing CLI programs, I can guarantee you that you will have a harder time writing GUI programs.

Comment: @gspr C++/CLI is not about command-line programs, it's Microsoft's language (based on C++) for Common Language Infrastructure.

Comment: Dev C++ is a) not a compiler b) hardly compatible with ISO C++ at all, if it's an old version. You can write native code with Visual Studio.

Comment: C++ generally uses Qt, wxWidgets, gtk or some other external libraries for GUIs. There isn't one in the standard library.

Comment: @Angew: Ah! I had no idea! Sorry.

Comment: You need a library to do the GUI. Qt, wxWidgets, GTK are cross-platform alternatives. Of these, Qt is IMO most usable (given that GTK is pure C). On Windows, you could also use MFC (I'm not even suggesting WinAPI), but I'm no expert on platform-specific GUI toolkits.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're stuck with Windows, some of the more popular choices are:

1. Microsoft [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Not for the faint of heart...
2. [Qt](http://qt-project.org). However, this is also not strictly ISO C++, as it requires a special pre-compilation step. But it comes with a very complete library, is cross platform and widely adopted. The documentation is excellent and the learning curve not very steep.
3. [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org). Cross-platfrom, popular and standard C++ only. However, relies heavily on the pre-processor and code using it tends to become ugly... (that's my personal opinion...)
4. [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/), which is pure C. There is a pretty decent C++ wrapper called [gtkmm](http://gtkmm.org).

Comment: It's funny to think that wxPython is way cleaner than the old C++ wxWidgets.

Comment: @Morwenn that's only because the ugliness is hidden away in the glue code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) is probably the best C++ GUI framework out there. It does include language extensions that are not 100% C++ but it comes pretty close. There are also tutorials to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ does not come with a gui. There are certain libraries that you could use to create a gui in c++ such as:

Qt
WxWidgets

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, C++/CLI is not C++, its Microsoft's ".net that looks like C++" language. Ignore it, it was pretty much dead on arrival.

I'm not sure what you mean by "pure ISO C++", if you mean you want to create a GUI app using C++ without any special language features (eg C++/CLI) then you'll be looking at [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) nowadays. Its really rather good and is probably the best C++ GUI system there is today. You can also download the QtCreator IDE that will help you out. (its also all open source and your apps will run on mobile and Linux too!)

If you want something that is Windows-only then you could write old MFC apps (for the desktop) or if you want to be bleeding-edge then write WinRT apps. The native OS GUI features are available in both these systems.